# display xml value in datagridview

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

i am working on UPS API . I request for address that is below

[image: informtaion i feel at form]

and i get the result in xml that is below . I want to bind the response value in datagridview. How can i do that .

```
    <AddressValidationResponse>
  <Response>
    <TransactionReference>
      <CustomerContext>test</CustomerContext>
      <XpciVersion>1.0001</XpciVersion>
    </TransactionReference>
    <ResponseStatusCode>1</ResponseStatusCode>
    <ResponseStatusDescription>Success</ResponseStatusDescription>
  </Response>
  <AddressValidationResult>
    <Rank>1</Rank>
    <Quality>0.75</Quality>
    <Address>
      <City>BATH</City>
      <StateProvinceCode>NH</StateProvinceCode>
    </Address>
    <PostalCodeLowEnd>03740</PostalCodeLowEnd>
    <PostalCodeHighEnd>03740</PostalCodeHighEnd>
  </AddressValidationResult>
  <AddressValidationResult>
    <Rank>2</Rank>
    <Quality>0.75</Quality>
    <Address>
      <City>BATH</City>
      <StateProvinceCode>ME</StateProvinceCode>
    </Address>
    <PostalCodeLowEnd>04530</PostalCodeLowEnd>
    <PostalCodeHighEnd>04530</PostalCodeHighEnd>
  </AddressValidationResult>
  <AddressValidationResult>
    <Rank>3</Rank>
    <Quality>0.75</Quality>
    <Address>
      <City>BATH</City>
      <StateProvinceCode>NY</StateProvinceCode>
    </Address>
    <PostalCodeLowEnd>14810</PostalCodeLowEnd>
    <PostalCodeHighEnd>14810</PostalCodeHighEnd>
  </AddressValidationResult>
  <AddressValidationResult>
    <Rank>4</Rank>
    <Quality>0.75</Quality>
    <Address>
      <City>BATH</City>
      <StateProvinceCode>PA</StateProvinceCode>
    </Address>
    <PostalCodeLowEnd>18014</PostalCodeLowEnd>
    <PostalCodeHighEnd>18014</PostalCodeHighEnd>
  </AddressValidationResult>
  <AddressValidationResult>
    <Rank>5</Rank>
    <Quality>0.75</Quality>
    <Address>
      <City>BATH</City>
      <StateProvinceCode>NC</StateProvinceCode>
    </Address>
    <PostalCodeLowEnd>27808</PostalCodeLowEnd>
    <PostalCodeHighEnd>27808</PostalCodeHighEnd>
  </AddressValidationResult>
  <AddressValidationResult>
    <Rank>6</Rank>
    <Quality>0.75</Quality>
    <Address>
      <City>BATH</City>
      <StateProvinceCode>SC</StateProvinceCode>
    </Address>
    <PostalCodeLowEnd>29816</PostalCodeLowEnd>
    <PostalCodeHighEnd>29816</PostalCodeHighEnd>
  </AddressValidationResult>
  <AddressValidationResult>
    <Rank>7</Rank>
    <Quality>0.75</Quality>
    <Address>
      <City>BATH</City>
      <StateProvinceCode>KY</StateProvinceCode>
    </Address>
    <PostalCodeLowEnd>41836</PostalCodeLowEnd>
    <PostalCodeHighEnd>41836</PostalCodeHighEnd>
  </AddressValidationResult>
  <AddressValidationResult>
    <Rank>8</Rank>
    <Quality>0.75</Quality>
    <Address>
      <City>BATH</City>
      <StateProvinceCode>OH</StateProvinceCode>
    </Address>
    <PostalCodeLowEnd>44210</PostalCodeLowEnd>
    <PostalCodeHighEnd>44210</PostalCodeHighEnd>
  </AddressValidationResult>
  <AddressValidationResult>
    <Rank>9</Rank>
    <Quality>0.75</Quality>
    <Address>
      <City>BATH</City>
      <StateProvinceCode>IN</StateProvinceCode>
    </Address>
    <PostalCodeLowEnd>47010</PostalCodeLowEnd>
    <PostalCodeHighEnd>47010</PostalCodeHighEnd>
  </AddressValidationResult>
  <AddressValidationResult>
    <Rank>10</Rank>
    <Quality>0.75</Quality>
    <Address>
      <City>BATH</City>
      <StateProvinceCode>MI</StateProvinceCode>
    </Address>
    <PostalCodeLowEnd>48808</PostalCodeLowEnd>
    <PostalCodeHighEnd>48808</PostalCodeHighEnd>
  </AddressValidationResult>
</AddressValidationResponse>
```

code for retrieve the xml

```
private void btnRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        TransactionRef.CustomerContext = txtCustomerContext.Text;
            Request.TransactionReference = TransactionRef;
            AddressReq.Request = Request;
            Address.City = txtcity.Text;

            Address.StateProvinceCode = txtStateProvinceCode.Text;
            AddressReq.Address = Address;
           AddressResponse res =   AddressMgr.CreateAddressRequest(AddressReq);

        }


 public AddressResponse CreateAddressRequest(AddressRequest addressrequest)
    {
        addressrequest.ServiceAccessToken.AccessLicenseNumber = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessLicenseNumber"];
        addressrequest.UsernameToken.Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"];
        addressrequest.UsernameToken.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]; 
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
        sb.Append("<AccessRequest xml:lang='en-US'>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<AccessLicenseNumber>{0}</AccessLicenseNumber>", addressrequest.ServiceAccessToken.AccessLicenseNumber);
        sb.AppendFormat("<UserId>{0}</UserId>", addressrequest.UsernameToken.Username);
        sb.AppendFormat("<Password>{0}</Password>",addressrequest.UsernameToken.Password);
        sb.Append("</AccessRequest>");
        sb.Append("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
        sb.Append("<AddressValidationRequest xml:lang='en-US'>");
        sb.Append("<Request>");
        sb.Append("<TransactionReference>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<CustomerContext>{0}</CustomerContext>",addressrequest.Request.TransactionReference.CustomerContext);
        sb.AppendFormat("<XpciVersion>1.0001</XpciVersion>");
        sb.Append("</TransactionReference>");
        sb.Append("<RequestAction>AV</RequestAction>");
        sb.Append("</Request>");
        sb.Append("<Address>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<City>{0}</City>", addressrequest.Address.City);
        sb.AppendFormat("<StateProvinceCode>{0}</StateProvinceCode>", addressrequest.Address.StateProvinceCode);
        sb.Append("</Address>");
        sb.Append("</AddressValidationRequest>");
        string requestString = sb.ToString();
        string XmlResponse = DoRequest("https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/AV", requestString);
        XDocument Xresponse = XDocument.Parse(XmlResponse);
        if (TransationRef == null)
             TransationRef = new TransactionReference();
        if (response == null)
            response = new Response();
        if (transactionref == null)
            transactionref = new TransactionReference();

        if (addressvalidationresult == null)
            addressvalidationresult = new List<AddressValidationResultType>();

        if (addressValidationResultType == null)
        addressValidationResultType = new AddressValidationResultType();

        if (addresstype == null)
            addresstype = new AddressType();

        if (AddressRes == null)
            AddressRes = new AddressResponse();

        foreach (XElement node in Xresponse.Elements("AddressValidationResponse"))
        {
            foreach (XElement ResponseNode in node.Descendants("Response"))
            {
                response.ResponseStatusCode = ResponseNode.Element("ResponseStatusCode").Value;
                response.ResponseStatusDescription = ResponseNode.Element("ResponseStatusDescription").Value;
               // AddressRes.Response = response;
                foreach (XElement TransactionReferenceNode in ResponseNode.Elements("TransactionReference"))
                {
                    transactionref.CustomerContext = TransactionReferenceNode.Element("CustomerContext").Value;
                    transactionref.XpciVersion = TransactionReferenceNode.Element("XpciVersion").Value;
                   // AddressRes.Response.TransactionReference = transactionref;
                }
            }

            foreach (XElement AddressValidationResultNode in node.Descendants("AddressValidationResult"))
            {


                addressValidationResultType.Rank = AddressValidationResultNode.Element("Rank").Value;
                addressValidationResultType.Quality = AddressValidationResultNode.Element("Quality").Value;
                addressValidationResultType.PostalCodeLowEnd = AddressValidationResultNode.Element("PostalCodeLowEnd").Value;
                addressValidationResultType.PostalCodeHighEnd = AddressValidationResultNode.Element("PostalCodeHighEnd").Value;

                foreach (XElement AddressNode in AddressValidationResultNode.Elements("Address"))
                {

                    addresstype.City = AddressNode.Element("City").Value;
                    addresstype.StateProvinceCode = AddressNode.Element("StateProvinceCode").Value;
                    addressValidationResultType.Address = addresstype;
                }
                addressvalidationresult.Add(addressValidationResultType);
                AddressRes.AddressValidationResult = addressvalidationresult; 

            }
        }

        return AddressRes;

    }
```

Thanks you in advance for your help

Comment: are you using winform or asp.net?

Comment: @Sajeetharan i am using winform

Comment: @A.Goutam how do you retrieve the `Xml` file? Is it from `WebService` ? could you provide the code please?

Comment: @Marek i have add the code please take a look

Comment: @A.Goutam See my answer, you can save the `Xdocument` first and then load it into the grid

Comment: @A.Goutam was my solution working properly in your case?

Comment: @Marek No :( not work at my project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55373/discussion-between-marek-and-a-goutam).